# FrameLayout with layout_weight is considered useless

Tags: android, layout, android-framelayout, android-layout-weight

Consider the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primary_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="Primary!"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondary_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="Secondary!"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

See the screenshot below for the result. The layout works fine, but Android Studio warns me that the `FrameLayout`s are considered useless and should be removed. However, they're not useless. I use `layout_weight` here. The idea is that the space between and around the two `TextView`s are relative with weights 2:1:3.

How can I rewrite my layout that results in the same weighted positioning of the views without having to use empty `FrameLayout`s?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you are missing "android:weightSum " in your root linearLayout.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about weightSum, and Android Studio doesn't complain. The documentation says it will be automatically computed when it is omitted. It's only necessary if you want to specify a maximum sum. But I'm not sure how this would help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FrameLayout` is a container that is supposed to have children. For a gap, a `View` is sufficient. I replaced each empty `FrameLayout`s with:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />
```

and the linter warning was gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the first two `FrameLayout` by setting the height of your `TextView` to 0dp and their weight to the values you set for your `FrameLayout`.

Comment: That way, the first TextView would stick at the very top. You probably meant replacing the last two FrameLayouts. That works if I keep the height of the TextView to wrap_content, because otherwise the text may get cropped when it becomes too long. Still the first FrameLayout remains...